# Doubt about Gardner' solution to bug chase problem

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

A famous Martin Gardner problem goes something like this. Four bugs are placed on the corners of a 10-inch side square. Each bug is looking at the bug to its right and starts to walk towards it. Tracing a logarithmic spiral, all the bugs meet at the center of the square (supposing that a bug has zero size obviously).
How long has each bug traveled?

Gardner states that this problem can be solved without calculus and each bug travels exactly 10 inches. I really don't intuitively get how it could be done without calculus, so my question(s) are:

1. Could someone please explain really easily how to solve this problem?
2. Does the same reasoning hold for a $n$-gon? i.e. is it true in general that $n$ bugs placed on the vertices of a $n$-gon of side $l$ chase each other in a spiral path which lenght is $l$? (My guess: no, because in the limit case of a circle the distance traveled is greater than the distance between bugs which is zero...or not?)

Comment: At every moment, the bugs form a square. The side of the square decreases at the same speed as the bugs move because the direction of one bug is the same as the side of the square and the next bug moves in an orthogonal direction.

Comment: Nothing strange to find a bug in a bug chase...

Comment: For an n-gon, the same reasoning apparently leads to a distance $\ell/(1-\cos\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between a side and the next side.

Comment: @Gribouillis I don't understand your reasoning, sorry, could you make it into an answer?

Comment: @Gribouillis Also, following the idea of a "shrinking polygon" it seems to me that the reasoning cannot work with a high number of sides...but idk

Comment: This is better known as the Mice problem, and is part of an area of mathematics called pursuits.

Comment: @marcotrevi Suppose the two ends of a segment move with speeds $v_1,v_2$ along the direction of the segment, then the change in the length of the segment during a short time $\,\Delta t\,$ is $\,(v_2-v_1) \Delta t\,$. For arbitrary speeds, not necessarily aligned with the segment, the components orthogonal to the segment do not change its length, so the same formula holds using the components alongside the segment - which is what Gribouillis' first comment meant.

Comment: Due to symmetry bugs are forming a square everytime. Projection of every bug velocity on direction to square center is constant and equal $v \cos 45^\circ=\frac{v}{\sqrt{2}}$. Then time is initial distance from center $\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$ divided by this projection: $t=\frac{a}{v}$. And traveled distance is time multiplied by velocity $l=tv=a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ {p}_{1} \left(t\right)$ and $ {p}_{2} \left(t\right)$ be the positions
of two consecutive bugs on the $n$-gon. Let $ s \left(t\right)$ be the
distance travelled by bug 1 since the beginning and let $ d \left(t\right) = \left\|{p}_{2} \left(t\right)-{p}_{1} \left(t\right)\right\|$ be the distance between the
two bugs.

One has

\begin{equation}{s'} \left(t\right) = \left\|{{p'}}_{1} \left(t\right)\right\| \qquad  {d'} \left(t\right) = \left({{p'}}_{2} \left(t\right)-{{p'}}_{1} \left(t\right)\right) \cdot  \frac{\left({p}_{2} \left(t\right)-{p}_{1} \left(t\right)\right)}{\left\|{p}_{2} \left(t\right)-{p}_{1} \left(t\right)\right\|}\end{equation}

Hence $ {d'} \left(t\right)$ is the projection of $ {{p'}}_{2}-{{p'}}_{1}$ onto the line joining $ {p}_{1}$ and $ {p}_{2}$
(a side of  the $ n$-gon).
It follows that

\begin{equation}{d'} \left(t\right) = \left(\cos  \left(\frac{2 {\pi}}{n}\right)-1\right) \left\|{{p'}}_{1} \left(t\right)\right\| = \left(\cos  \left(\frac{2 {\pi}}{n}\right)-1\right) {s'} \left(t\right)\end{equation}

When the bugs meet up, we have

\begin{equation}{-\ell } = d \left(t\right)-d \left(0\right) = \int_{0}^{t}{d'} \left(u\right) d u =-\left(1-\cos  \left(\frac{2 {\pi}}{n}\right)\right) s \left(t\right)\end{equation}

The distance travelled by each bug is

\begin{equation}\boxed{s = \frac{\ell }{1-\cos  \left(\frac{2 {\pi}}{n}\right)}}\end{equation}

**Complete trajectory**

We can give a complete parametrization of the bugs' trajectories by
using complex numbers. Let $ {\theta} = \frac{2 {\pi}}{n}$ and
$ {\omega} = \cos  {\theta}+i \sin  {\theta}$. Let

\begin{equation}{z}_{k} \left(t\right) = \frac{\ell }{\left|{\omega}-1\right|} {e}^{\left({\omega}-1\right) t} {{\omega}}^{k} , \qquad  k = 0 , \ldots  , n-1\end{equation}

Clearly, these $n$ complex numbers form a $n$-gon centered at
$0$ and one has

\begin{equation}{{z'}}_{k} = \frac{\ell }{\left|{\omega}-1\right|} {e}^{\left({\omega}-1\right) t} {{\omega}}^{k} \left({\omega}-1\right) = {z}_{k+1}-{z}_{k}\end{equation}

which means that $ {z}_{k}$ moves instantly towards
$ {z}_{k+1}$, and
when $ t = 0$ we have $\left|{z}_{k+1}-{z}_{k}\right| = \ell $.
It follows that $ {z}_{k} \left(t\right)$ is a parametrization of the trajectories
of the bugs. The bugs meet when $ t = \infty $ and we have directly
the distance travelled

\begin{equation}s = \int_{0}^{\infty }\left|{z'} \left(t\right)\right| d t = \ell  \int_{0}^{\infty }{e}^{\left(\cos  {\theta}-1\right) t} d t = \frac{\ell }{1-\cos  {\theta}}\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks, but I was really interested in how it could be solved without calculus.

Comment: When I say at the beginning that the variation of distance between the bugs is equal to $(1 - \cos \theta)$ times the variation of distance travelled, there is no calculus at all. It is only a remark that there is a constant proportionality between the two. Bug 1 moves towards bug 2 at speed $|p'_1|$ and bug 2 moves away from bug 1 at speed $|p'_2|\cos\theta$, but $|p'_1| = |p'_2|$ because the bugs have the same velocity.